# Can linear programs in canonical form be infeasible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming

Is one of the stipulations of putting a linear program in canonical form that it must have at least one feasible solution? Also, if a canonical linear program can be infeasible, does that mean any linear program can be converted to canonical form?

Answer (score 2):

Programs in canonical form can be infeasible. For example, the following LP is infeasible:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mbox{maximize } & x_1 + x_2 \\
\mbox{s.t. }     & x_1 - x_2 = -1 \\
                 & x_1 + x_2 = -4 \\
                 & x_1, x_2 \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally, any LP can be brought into canonical form. Inequalities can be turned into equalities by introducing slack variables, and "free" variables can be rewritten as the difference of two nonnegative variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to your question about the canonical form (or standard form in some optimization literature) having at least one feasible solution: a standard form LP, when it is feasible, must have at least one *basic* feasible solution. In other words, the polyhedron associated with the constraints must have an extreme point, when nonempty. This is one of the reasons that an LP is transformed to standard form for computation, like using the Simplex method.